# Score between range PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to create a program that returns a specific codes within my if statement.

Score below 70: display the score in h1 tag and display in h2 tag their grade: D

Score between 70-80: display the score in h1 tag and display in h2 tag their grade: C

Score between 80-90: display the score in h1 tag and display in h2 tag their grade: B;

if someone got 80, give them a B
Score between 90-100: display the score in h1 tag and display in h2 tag their grade: A;

if someone got 90, give them an A
For example, the output of your code would be something like below:

here's my codes:

```
function random(){
    $number = rand(50,100);
    echo "<h1> Your Score: {$number}/100 </h1>"; 

    if($number>70){
        echo "<h2>Your Grade is D</h2>";
    }else if($number=(range(70, 80))){
        echo "<h2>Your Grade is C</h2>";
    }else if($number=(range(80, 90))){
        echo "<h2>Your Grade is B</h2>";
    }else if($number==80){
        echo "<h2>Your Grade is B</h2>";
    }else if($number=(range(90, 100))){
        echo "<h2>Your Grade is A</h2>";
    }


}

$score = random();
echo $score;
```

Currently it is not showing up the correct grades and text. Any idea?

Comment: the logic behind the if statement is incorrect, you need first to check the higher bounds , because the number that is between 70 and 80 is also greater than 70 so all your cases will stop at the first IF

Comment: `else if($number=(range(70, 80))){` will always return true, because you are assing an array to `$number` which will always succeed

Comment: Any idea then how to fix it?

Comment: `elseif(70<$number<80){`

Comment: Also note that `$score = random();` will actually `echo` the result, because the function is echoing and not returning. See my answer below for a solution :)

Answer (score 3):

The logic behind your `if` statement is wrong.

Also note that `$score = random();` will actually `echo` the result, because the function is echoing and not returning anything.

Try this:

```
function random(){

    //Generate random number and create a string that will be returned
    $number = rand(50,100);
    $result = "<h1> Your Score: {$number}/100 </h1>"; 

    //Decide what grade the number gets
    if($number>=90){
        $grade = "A";
    } elseif($number>=80){
        $grade = "B";
    } elseif($number>=70){
        $grade = "C";
    } else {
        $grade = "D";
    }

    //Add the grade to the result and return it
    $result .= "<h2>Your grade is $grade</h2>";
    return $result;

}

$score = random();
echo $score;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is just a little out at the moment.

The numbers should start at the largest and work down, otherwise it will hit the `> 70` and it will instantly fit into that bracket.

```
<?php
    function random(){
        $number = rand(50,100);
        echo "<h1> Your Score: {$number}/100 </h1>"; 

        if($number >= 90){
            echo "<h2>Your Grade is A</h2>";
        }else if($number >= 80){
            echo "<h2>Your Grade is B</h2>";
        }else if($number >= 70){
            echo "<h2>Your Grade is C</h2>";
        }else if($number < 70){
            echo "<h2>Your Grade is D</h2>";
        }


    }

    $score = random();
    echo $score;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your conditional statements are flawed, a rough way to do this could be like the following

```
$grade = "FAIL"; $tag = "h5";
if ($number >= 70) {
    $grade = "C"; $tag = "h4";
}
if ($number >= 80) {
    $grade = "B"; $tag = "h3";
}
if ($number >= 90) {
    $grade = "A"; $tag = "h2";
}
echo "<".$tag.">Your Grade is ".$grade."</".$tag.">";
```

This method will first set your values for ultimate failure, then if the number meets the criteria of each condition, the values are overwritten until no more conditions are met.